# single word for dark smelly fart / farting without noise

Tags: word-request

In our local language (India->Maharashtra->Kolhapur) we have two different words for fart.

1. When a person farts with (hearable) noise (smelly or not smelly) we call this farting 'Padla'(male=पदला) / 'Padli' (female=पदली).
2. When a person farts without noise and we come to know because of dark smell, we call it 'Thuski'(ठुस्की).

> So what is this 'Thuski' called in english?

No doubt everybody will be having their own calling name for this.
After some answers, i edited the question a bit.
I want a **single word** (no multiple words) with locality name as i have mentioned. So, please tell the word with your locality.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, don't women fart?

Comment: No, of course not, "sugar and spice and everything nice", and if they did (hypothetically) roses or such would come to mind [here](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/bf/e1/46/bfe146524a78f679f64e1ff80afe8ab5.jpg). What a silly question! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't, to my knowledge, a common single word for this phenomenon.  Which is actually kind of surprising.

Answer (score 8):

The standard term in the English I know is ["silent but deadly".](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Silent+but+deadly)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I want a single word. I know everybody will have their own calling name for this. But i would appreciate a locality word with locality name. Checkout, I am editing the question.

Comment: (I'm in the Eastern US.) I don't think there is a single word in English for this. There won't necessarily be a word in English for every word in your language, unfortunately.

Comment: **silent but violent** is the one we use. I'm with Ken on this one: I don't think there's a single word in English that conveys this.

Comment: **SBVD** = silent but very deadly, read as the four letter abbreviation (ess-bee-vee-dee)

Comment: In search of more gems by the admirable Eddie Izzard, I watched [Mystery Men](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0132347/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) last night (a bunch of zany "wannabe superheros" save the world; a bit daft, but quite amusing). Anyway, one of the motley crew, called "Spleen" has the somewhat unusual superpower of being able to produce "weaponized" farts at will. At 39m34s (after calibrating for distance, elevation, wind speed, etc.) he lets rip, saying **S! B! D! - Silent, but deadly.** as the bad guys all collapse, gasping for breath. I think **SBD** is pretty well-known, in the UK at least.

Comment: What is it about elimination of body waste and gas that makes them such a fertile (sorry...) field for idiom? I include here even emesis, which yields such evocative wonders as _rainbow smile_ and _driving the porcelain bus._

Answer (score 3):

A little late to jump in on this, but "air biscuit" is another one. You can't see it, but it's thick enough to chew.

Comment: Interesting addition. Would you include an example of how it's used in a sentence?

Comment: + 1 One _floats_ that biscuit; this is right up there with _cut a muffin,_ and even partakes of the bakery theme! (A link to, say, _idioms.thefreedictionary.com_ might make this answer even better....) Welcome to ELL and thanks for your answer. If you haven't done so, please take a few minutes to review our [**tour**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages.

Answer (score 2):

In Miriam Webster dictionary the word for a silent fart is a fizzle coming from a now unused middle English verb Feist, which has the same meaning.

Comment: i  checked Miriam Webster online dictionary, but i didn't find this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the validity of this word. But as inspired by the functionality and highly influenced by the media, I'll suggest a word, which has no exact definition to the one you want, but metaphorically can be implied.

> **SILENCER**

According to Wiki, '[Silencer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silencer)' refers to an attachment to an otherwise noisy device, thereby to suppress or muffle the noise. Let me explain why I suggested this word.

A silencer is very familiar to us as we know it be the elongated pipe-like device that we attach to the end of a pistol to muffle the noise when a bullet is fired. Now, imagine a fart, with no noise, yet is strong enough to kill (again, 'kill' metaphorically. Because farts cannot kill people, or so I hope). Now you wanted a word to define a noise-less fart, which is also lethal. So maybe this word can help. But in itself, you cannot use *"silencer"* to define a fart and expect a listener to understand.

**Note**: I repeat, this is strictly **metaphorically**.

Answer (score -1):

I once heard that Aussie slang for a silent fart was "sneaker".

Comment: Can you please cite a source to back up your claim?